# Can a python webapp be bundled into a single file for deployment?

Tags: python, deployment

Is it possible for a python webapp to be bundled (gzipped?) into a single file, along with any required resources (js/css files) & modules (including modules like lxml which are mostly C-based), for easy deployment onto a linux webserver?

Comment: This depends somewhat on the platform you'll be using it on (so maybe tell us).  Also, if you have any eggs or any use of pkg_resources, you're in for a world of hurt with many of the packaging tools...

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can create a windows executable using `py2exe`.  A better way to manage deployment is to package your app with a `setup.py` file, listing all needed dependencies, and listing non-python support files in the `MANIFEST.in` file.  Then you can package it into a bundle using `setup.py sdist`, and install it with `pip`.  See Tarek Ziade's [Hitchhiker's Guide to Packaging](http://guide.python-distribute.org/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

For standalones ,you could try :

OS X : [py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html)

For Windows [py2exe](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/).

Not sure if this would apply to your 'webapp' though.

Answer (score 0):

[PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) is perhaps the best cross-platform packager (in the SVN trunk version: 1.3, the latest packaged release, is very old and crufty -- no idea why my friends who took over maintenance over a year ago and did so many enhancements keep resisting my entreaties to make another release, already!-) -- you can package for Windows, Linux or Mac, and it directly supports many popular third-party packages too.